# Importing 3rd party module using Py2exe - Specifically 'pattern.en'

Tags: python, py2exe

There is a module named 'pattern.en' available at www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en. I am using this module for some lexical analysis. I then use py2exe to convert this code into an executable file.
Here's the code for the first file named -'pattern_import.py' :

```
import pattern.en
Sent = 'LinearRegression fits a linear model with coefficients.'
print pattern.en.tag(Sent)
```

The content of the file that I plan to use to convert the program to exe is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
import sys

from glob import glob

sys.argv.append('py2exe')
sys.path.append('C:\Python27\lib\site-packages')

setup(windows=[{'script': 'pattern_import.py'}], \
        options={"py2exe": {"includes": ["decimal", "Tkinter", \
        "tkFileDialog", "csv", "xml.dom.minidom", "os", "pattern.en"], \

        'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': False}}, \
        zipfile = None)
```

When I run this, I get the executable file. However when I run the exe file, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pattern.en_import.py", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named en
```

But when I run the Python file, it runs and gives what I want.

What am I doing wrong.